# Can't find variable: PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying some react native code.

Added props for my component based on the instructions given in this [blog](https://codeburst.io/props-and-state-in-react-native-explained-in-simple-english-8ea73b1d224e).

End up in the error, Can't find variable: PropTypes
Found the same question in [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20852) but it was closed without any answers

Couldn't get any clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do install prop-types with `npm install --save prop-types` or `yarn add prop-types` and then add this to your code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure prop-types is installed:
  `npm install --save prop-types`
- Make sure the following line is added in the file where the error originated
  `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was having a similar issue when configuring my react router (react-router-dom),
then I realized I used YARN to add react, react-dom and prop-types, and NPM to add the react-router-dom, then I got suspicious it was this the problem and I:

removed it with:
npm uninstall react-router-dom

and installed it with:
yarn add react-router-dom --dev

and it stopped giving me the error / fixed it.